# How to wait for Word Object to complete?

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to run a VBScript to do some operations within a Word file (heavy).

```
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open(fileName)
objWord.Visible = False
' Do heavy work here.
' Do heavy work here.
objDoc.SaveAs(file.ParentFolder & "/" & theBaseName & " _compiled")
```

When this script is called from the command line, there is no way to tell when it has completed as it runs "asynchronously".

How do I wait for process completion?

Comment: Use `Start` in command line with option to wait.

Comment: that simple ? I feel embarrassed. I'm gonna give it a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be running the script with `wscript.exe`. Use `cscript.exe` to run VBScripts synchronously from a console or batch script.

```
cscript.exe //NoLogo "C:\path\to\your.vbs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `WScript.Echo Now()` at the top and bottom of the script; you'll see the code runs synchronously. When you get the second message box, instead of clicking OK, check for the file you're saving as; it will be present.